# Google Analytics - Extract User Activity Historical and Daily Data

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've been trying to extract and loop through the User Activity API to extract historical data and create a daily feed for each GA profile, but run into the "10,000 requests per view (profile) per day" quota limit as I have ~50,000 users per day.

My current script loops through each `CLIENT_ID` one by one and extracts the user_activity as shown below and following this documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/userActivity/search

```
## List of CLIENT_IDs extracted from batch.get() reports API
CLIENT_ID = ['x','y','z']
START_DATE = '2020-01-01'
END_DATE = '2022-01-01'

    for client_id in CLIENT_ID:

        data = analytics.userActivity().search(
            body={
                "viewId": VIEW_ID,
                "pageSize": 1000000000,
                "user": {
                    "type": "CLIENT_ID",
                    "userId": str(client_id),
                },
                'dateRange': {"startDate": str(START_DATE),
                              "endDate": str(END_DATE)
                              }
                             ,
            }
        ).execute()
        print(data)
```

Is there a better way of extracting this historical data without running into the API quota limit for each profile and pinging multiple users at the same time? I've also tried to create more than one profile in GCP to by-pass the quota limit, but with no success.

In the front-end of GA3, there's no way to extract this raw data so any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three types of quotas for the Google analytics apis.

- User based quotas
- View based quotas
- Project based quotas.

## View Based Quotas

View based Quotas are based upon each view that you are accessing. They can not be extended.

See: [limits-quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

[image]

## user based quotas

User based quotas are based upon the user who is accessing the data, either by the authorization of the user whos account you are using to access the data, or by the ip address of the system running the code.  These quotas are often used for flood protection to ensure that your system is not running to fast.

user based quotas can not be extended.

## Project based quotas.

Project based quotas are the quota that define your project as a whole. The default project based quota is 50k and this can be extended.

[image]

So to answer your question.  The 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day quota is a view based quota that can not be extended.  Your best option would be to make fewer requests and only request the data you need.  you can also do it over a number of days.

If you are requesting it for more then 5 views and there for hitting the project based quota you can apply for an extension.

There is also an option of exporting your data to BigQuery which removes the limits but its not free from what I remember  see: [Set up BigQuery Export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) It is also not a python solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I've already received an increase in project based quota and do make fewer requests per view. I've also tried to generate multiple access tokens from different users to run the code to request 10,000 requests per view, but still end up hitting the limit. Do you know if there's a way to make more profiles in GCP with different tokens that doesn't hit that limit?

Comment: There is no way.  Theres a limit on how much data can be extracted from a view per day.  If you have an app and i have an app and we both try to read from the same view we share the limit.    I will bring it up to the team again, but its been an issue for ten years.  They havent changed it yet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this again - do you know if the exporting the data to BigQuery solution will have the same granularity as the User Activity API? I'd only want to have a one-off export of historical user activity data (as one cost) as opposed to migrating to Google 360 entirely.

Comment: Big query will let you export everything as far as i know.   You actually have more power with what you export if you use big query.   The api is more limited.